# Command to list services that start on startup?

Tags: services, upstart, systemd, init.d

Is there a command to list services that run on startup? I imagine it would involve parsing `/etc/init.d/`, and the various `/etc/rc.*` directories.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can simply use the `initctl list` shell command to list the contents of `/etc/init` rather than the suggested `dbus-send` command.

Comment: Does this work in Ubuntu 18.04? I get "initctl: command not found" (in bash)

Comment: `initctl list` does not found on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @RémyHosseinkhanBoucher For more recent version of Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/a/1167921/988056

Answer (score 197):

The quick answer is:  It depends on your `init` system.

The long answer is:  For current versions of Ubuntu, you probably have a mix of [Upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart), and [SystemV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V).  Newer versions of Ubuntu after 15.04 "Vivid Vervet" (and other Linux distros like RHEL/CentOS 7) are moving to use [SystemD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

## Upstart

- [Upstart Documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

To list all services:

```
sudo initctl list
```

To list all Upstart services and run `initctl show-config` on them, this one-liner may be helpful:

```
sudo initctl list | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -n1 initctl show-config
```

## System V

- [SysV Runlevels Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-sysv.html)

To list all services:

```
sudo service --status-all
```

OR:

```
# for init scripts:
ls /etc/init.d/

# for runlevel symlinks:
ls /etc/rc*.d/
```

## SystemD

- [SystemD for Upstart Users](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)
- [FedoraProject SystemD Documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#systemd_documentation)
- [RHEL 7: Managing Services with SystemD](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html)
- [RedHat: SystemD Overview](https://access.redhat.com/articles/754933)

To list all services:

```
sudo systemctl --all list-unit-files --type=service
```

OR:

```
ls /lib/systemd/system/*.service /etc/systemd/system/*.service
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `service --status-all` does NOT show whether services are enabled to start on boot, at least not on Ubuntu 16.  It shows whether services are *currently running* or not.

Comment: I had to `sudo service --status-all` to get _all_ of the services to show up. A few were hidden when I only ran `service --status-all` on a non-root account.

Comment: @Phlucious : Thanks for mentioning that.  I assumed it was well known that these commands are usually run as root (`systemctl`, `service`, `initctl`...)  as they are usually considered system administration commands.

Comment: `service --status-all` This command worked in my `debian` box too

Comment: The OP asked for services starting on startup, so you need the `--state enabled` bit to systemctl. And as man page state `service --status-all` will return if they are running or not, not if they are set to run on startup

Answer (score 15):

For Ubuntu 18.04 use :

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

instead of `initctl`.

Since Ubuntu 16.04, `initctl` has been replaced by **`systemd`** ([source](https://www.linuxtricks.fr/wiki/systemd-les-commandes-essentielles), in French).

If it can [help @sanjay-manohar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218/command-to-list-services-that-start-on-startup#comment1944310_6649).

Answer (score 13):

The `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/rc.*` directories have been superseded by the '`upstart`' init tool. Although scripts in these directories will be executed as expected, the new method for running things on init is defined by files in `/etc/init/`

You can list all of the upstart jobs with by querying upstart over dbus:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=com.ubuntu.Upstart \
        /com/ubuntu/Upstart com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.GetAllJobs
```

You may have to change `0_6` to reflect the version of upstart you have. This command works on my lucid install.

Comment: @Eric H: Could your set the answer below as correct instead - `initctl list` is much nicer than this dbus command. I'd like to leave this answer here for reference (rather than deleting it completely) though.

Answer (score 12):

If you want a nice graphical representation of services and time it takes to boot try:

```
sudo apt install bootchart
```

For systemd (since 16.04) try [systemd-bootchart](https://github.com/systemd/systemd-bootchart/) instead:

```
sudo apt install systemd-bootchart
```

Answer (score 11):

Id use `initctl show-config <servicename>` to really get the details of when/if your service will start during boot.

Like so:

```
$ initctl show-config myservice
myservice
  start on runlevel [2345]
  stop on runlevel [!2345]
```

Or for NFS4 idmap-daemon:

```
$ initctl show-config idmapd
idmapd
  start on (local-filesystems or mounting TYPE=nfs4)
  stop on runlevel [06]
```

chkconfig is only preferable on RedHat based systems imho.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have no idea why all the wrong and incomplete answers are so highly upvoted.

Comment: This doenst work for people using SysV, I agree this it a good answer but it is incomplete.

Answer (score 9):

On 12.04 we could use:

```
sudo apt-get install chkconfig
chkconfig --list
```

but it was [removed in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221293/why-is-chkconfig-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu).

Sample output:

```
acpi-support              0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
acpid                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
apparmor                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=chkconfig&searchon=names

Comment: @A.B. thanks for letting me know! It is rare for downvoters to comment nowadays: it requires courage and allows me to learn. updated with the version it works in.

Comment: On Precise: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/chkconfig

Answer (score 5):

Besides system services and scripts under:

> */etc/init.d/*
>   */lib/systemd/system/*
>   */etc/systemd/system/*

There are probably **AutoStart Applications** too, for example:

```
find / -name "*autostart*"

ls -1 "/etc/xdg/autostart" "/home/$USER/.config/autostart" "/usr/share/gdm/autostart"  "/usr/share/gnome/autostart"
```

Answer (score -1):

Using gawk:

```
ls -l /etc/rc*.d/* | gawk 'match($0, /rc([0-6S]).d.*\/(.*)$/, a) {l[a[2]]=l[a[2]]a[1]","}; END{for(v in l){print v,substr(l[v],1,length(l[v])-1)}}'
```

Sample output:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc*.d/* | gawk 'match($0, /rc([0-6S]).d.*\/(.*)$/, a) {l[a[2]]=l[a[2]]a[1]","}; END{for(v in l){print v,substr(l[v],1,length(l[v])-1)}}' | egrep README
README 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,S
```