# Why is chkconfig no longer available in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, services, autostart

I can not use chkconfig tools in Ubuntu 12.10

It's a very useful tools to configure the service to autostart or not. Why is it no longer available?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

*sysv-rc-conf* is an alternate option for Ubuntu.

The usage is almost the same.

#### To install:

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

#### To configure *apache2* to start on boot

```
sysv-rc-conf apache2 on
```

equivalent *chkconfig* command

```
chkconfig apache2 enable
```

#### To check runlevels *apache2* is configured to start on

```
sysv-rc-conf --list apache2
```

equivalent *chkconfig* command

```
chkconfig --list apache2
```

Comment: adding ... create an alias with the name chkconfig for sysv-rc-conf

Comment: For all who are puzzled about Upstart: There is no way to enable/disable Upstart type services in a common or automated fashion.  According to [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto): `Upstart: If no config is available in /etc/default, edit config in /etc/init` which reads to me like "improving a bad situation means for us making it unbearable".  Hence no wonder package maintainers with a healthy mind stay with RC type initscripts.

Comment: @Tino, package managers' decision to refrain from providing Upstart configs is an entirely different debate from the issue the OP's question poses. While it does deserve a forum and due discussion, I don't feel that comment is really warranted here.

Comment: To note: just running `sysv-rc-conf` with no options yields a comfortable interface to manage it.

Comment: Unfortunately, sysv-rc-conf is not available for Ubuntu and I got "E: Unable to locate package sysv-rc-conf" when I used apt-get install sysv-rc-conf.

Answer (score 9):

The **Upstart** equivalent of *chkconfig* is the [*update-rc.d*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html). There's some info on how to use it in the UbuntuBootupHowto linked in [L. D. James](https://askubuntu.com/users/29012/l-d-james)'s answer.

Admittedly, this tool is anything but friendly; it tends to expose the ugly underbelly of **SysV init** with all it's gory runlevel and priority blackmagic. I have almost never managed to get it to do what I want in the first go. *chkconfig* did a fantastic job of abstracting all those numbers away and providing a simple, usable interface that was loved by all. Nevertheless, it was always lipstick on a pig.

It's a brave new world and I would suggest you put in some time towards learning how [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com) works so that you can wire new jobs using that. For existing packages/applications that still provide you with **SysV init** scripts, *update-rc.d* should allow you to do everything that *chkconfig* did, except for one usecase. *update-rc.d* provides no clean way to see what the current status of a given service is, i.e., there is no equivalent of `chkconfig --list`. For this particular case, I'd suggest `ls -l /etc/rc*.d/*${service_name}`.

HTH

**Update: 12-June-2013**
The answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/161893/111294 points to a more palatable alternative- *sysv-rc-conf*.

**Update: 28-July-2013**
Hmm... it appears that the OP has already answered here (https://askubuntu.com/a/277732/111294) suggesting *sysv-rc-conf*. Can't see how I missed that, have upvoted that answer now.

Comment: Upstart is to starting the service, I want the service do not start when I reboot my OS. Why the friendly tools is deprecated? and the unfriendly tools take it's place

Comment: Like I said above, I agree that update-rc.d is an unfriendly tool and it is somewhat unfortunate that it has been discontinued on Ubuntu. That said, it was always a RHEL family tool that had been ported to Ubuntu.

As for avoiding services from starting on booting into a particular runlevel, this can be achieved using Upstart as well. Just look at the 'start on runlevel' line in /etc/init/cron.conf .

Answer (score 2):

chkconfig is a redhat-ism. In Ubuntu we use upstart instead of sysvinit as used by redhat.

Comment: Could you give a example?


I could use chkconfig in the earlier release of ubuntu. But not now!

Comment: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/  has many many examples of upstart use, which can help greatly if the examples at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html do not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

on 13.10, none of the above 'solutions' work. Ran sysv-rc-conf, update-rc.d. Nada. sysv-rc-conf says bluetooth is off but it still runs. meh

Says it has been converted to upstart but nothing on how to disable the daemon, where the configuation for upstart is, etc, etc.

So, digging around, you can edit /etc/init/bluetooth.conf and just comment things out, presumably only the following is necessary (though I commented anything that looks relevant):

# exec /usr/sbin/bluetoothd

This will probably break with an upgrade but at least the bloody thing is off for a while.

Answer (score 0):

As of 12.04, chkconfig could be installed using `sudo apt-get install chkconfig`.

I would recommend using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

**Jobservice**, along with **jobs-admin** is a GUI based tool for handling *some* upstart scripts if that is your preference. It can be installed from the software center or by running `sudo apt-get install jobservice jobs-admin` from a terminal.

If I recall, there did not appear to be an easy way to add new jobs from the GUI.

Comment: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/ has some good infor for N00bs Like Me.

Comment: jobs-admin 0.8.0 doesn't work in Ubuntu 13.10 :(

Answer (score 0):

Else install chkconfig from Debian packages pool :

https://packages.debian.org/sid/chkconfig

Answer (score 0):

> Why is chkconfig no longer available in Ubuntu?

Well, there is some history behind. `chkconfig` is connected with UNIX System V or SysV (pronounced: "System Five").

Since then, Ubuntu switched to `Upstart`, and then again it switched to `systemd`.

`systemd` uses `systemctl` which reflects what was `chkconfig` to `SysV`.

---

From the man page :

> systemctl may be used to introspect and control the state of the "systemd" system and service manager. Please refer to systemd(1) for an introduction into the basic concepts and functionality
>          this tool manages.