# How can I install Adobe Flash media server on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit system

Tags: 12.04

I need to install Adobe Flash media server on my ubuntu 12.04 lTS 32-bit system,  How can I do it?

Comment: Adobe already offers a step-by-step instruction document for their Media Server. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I followed those instruction, while installing I get error as "./installFMS: 1346: ./installFMS: /sbin/chkconfig: not found"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install `chkconfig`:

`sudo apt-get install chkconfig`

If there is no package `chkconfig` available for 12.04, install `sysv-rc-conf` instead and define an alias, like this:

`alias chkconfig='sysv-rc-conf'`

and try again. For more details, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221293/why-is-chkconfig-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu).

Comment: I tried this one. Now it showing "/sbin/insserv : No such file or directory". I checked for insserv, it is already the newest version.

Comment: Apparently, the instructions were compiled for a Debian system, which is close to, but not the same as, an Ubuntu system. You will need to improvise a little. In the Ubuntu distribution, the package `insserv` does not install a file /sbin/insserv. Therefore, you should define a symbolic link: `sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/update-rc.d-insserv /sbin/insserv` and try again.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o2hb4.png. This is what I got after your instructions

Comment: The script `server` contains illegal commands or commands that have the wrong syntax in your current shell. I suggest that you either take this up with Adobe, try to edit the `server` script yourself, or ask a separate question.

Comment: I've edited the script server. Just changed #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash and I can able to start the server. But, now if I want to access localhost from browser it displays "403 FORBIDDEN". In widows if we just access localhost we get Flash Media Server's index page. I want same thing with ubuntu.

Comment: In the current version of Apache, the server root has moved to `/var/www/html`. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944/where-to-place-my-local-website-starting-with-the-2-4-7-version-of-apache2