# How to List down/check the services which will run on boot time

Tags: boot

How to check which service will be start at boot time.And also how to enable or disable any service from boot time.

Comment: You can refer the below url to know about the list of services which was run during the boot time. http://askubuntu.com/questions/218/command-to-list-services-that-start-on-startup

Comment: for list of services not for one service.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment is using `systemd` to start services at boot time then you can use the command line tool called `systemd-analyze` You need to specify what distribution you are using.to list the services which starts at boot time you can use the below command,

`systemd-analyze blame user`

You can list the services with respect to system and user. For more information `systemd-analyze --help`.